# how to add a watermark or logo to page when printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, text-editor

I have a [text-editor](https://unripened-amperes.000webhostapp.com/)

and i want a script so our logo or watermark will be in the printed page  in the text-editor automatically without inserting our logo or watermark in the text-editor that is made by contenteditable because user can just delete it and I tried certain tricks but all of them are quick-fixes that does not work in my text-editor and be by-passed by certain users is there any solution or idea or hint that can help me ? and this is the [script](http://jsfiddle.net/talabe/1d8uyknh/1/) of the text-editor

```js
var oDoc, sDefTxt;

function initDoc() {
  oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
  sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
  if (document.compForm.switchMode.checked) { setDocMode(true); }
}

function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {
  if (validateMode()) { document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue); oDoc.focus(); }
}

function validateMode() {
  if (!document.compForm.switchMode.checked) { return true ; }
  alert("Uncheck \"Show HTML\".");
  oDoc.focus();
  return false;
}

function setDocMode(bToSource) {
  var oContent;
  if (bToSource) {
    oContent = document.createTextNode(oDoc.innerHTML);
    oDoc.innerHTML = "";
    var oPre = document.createElement("pre");
    oDoc.contentEditable = false;
    oPre.id = "sourceText";
    oPre.contentEditable = true;
    oPre.appendChild(oContent);
    oDoc.appendChild(oPre);
    document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "div");
  } else {
    if (document.all) {
      oDoc.innerHTML = oDoc.innerText;
    } else {
      oContent = document.createRange();
      oContent.selectNodeContents(oDoc.firstChild);
      oDoc.innerHTML = oContent.toString();
    }
    oDoc.contentEditable = true;
  }
  oDoc.focus();
}




function printDoc() {
 if (!validateMode()) { return; }
var printContents = document.getElementById('textBox').innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}




var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return function (rule) {
        style.innerHTML = rule;
    };
}());

cssPagedMedia.margin = function (margin) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {margin: ' + margin + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.margin('0');

cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return function (rule) {
        style.innerHTML = rule;
    };
}());

cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.size('portrait');
```

Comment: Anything you can add they can remove

Comment: Why not use `javascript` to add a footer with your watermark/logo to `printContents` in your `printDoc()` function?

Comment: epascarello  Is there a script that will be outside that the text-editor this script jib is to insert a watermark to any printed page

Comment: This is something you would have to create and test for yourself. The only way to know if it is possible is by reading and understanding your current source code and attempt to modify it or create a function that will work with existing source. You haven't explained what you have tried or shown any attempt(s) of your own so my help will only be suggestions since I have no attempt to debug and try fix.

Comment: NewToJS can you please show me an example or shiuld i post the script of my editor ?

Comment: You need to re-read his comment, then read this site’s FAQ, and finally edit/fix your question.

Comment: NewToJS  I have posted the script of the text-editor so you have look into it

Comment: Please take a look at this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/vgaemkob/)

Comment: NewToJS i saw the script it still has the same problem the watermark get deleted

Comment: @HAMID Those down votes are no doubt because you didn't show or explain of any attempt(s) of your own. I didn't down vote because I wanted to give you chance to update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in my comments above, you can modify/add to the **printContents** variable inside of your `printDoc()` function.

I have created a variable `WaterMark` which you can replace with your logo/watermark.

Here is a [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/0jnw95v2/) and a working snippet below.

```js
var oDoc, sDefTxt;

function initDoc() {
  oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
  sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
  if (document.compForm.switchMode.checked) {
    setDocMode(true);
  }
}

function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {
  if (validateMode()) {
    document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue);
    oDoc.focus();
  }
}

function validateMode() {
  if (!document.compForm.switchMode.checked) {
    return true;
  }
  alert("Uncheck \"Show HTML\".");
  oDoc.focus();
  return false;
}

function setDocMode(bToSource) {
  var oContent;
  if (bToSource) {
    oContent = document.createTextNode(oDoc.innerHTML);
    oDoc.innerHTML = "";
    var oPre = document.createElement("pre");
    oDoc.contentEditable = false;
    oPre.id = "sourceText";
    oPre.contentEditable = true;
    oPre.appendChild(oContent);
    oDoc.appendChild(oPre);
    document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "div");
  } else {
    if (document.all) {
      oDoc.innerHTML = oDoc.innerText;
    } else {
      oContent = document.createRange();
      oContent.selectNodeContents(oDoc.firstChild);
      oDoc.innerHTML = oContent.toString();
    }
    oDoc.contentEditable = true;
  }
  oDoc.focus();
}




function printDoc() {
  if (!validateMode()) {
    return;
  }
  // Add your watermark here  
  var WaterMark = '<div style="width:150px;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;opacity:.8;">StackOverFlow</div>';
  var printContents = document.getElementById('textBox').innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents + WaterMark;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
/*page margin*/
var cssPagedMedia = (function() {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  return function(rule) {
    style.innerHTML = rule;
  };
}());

cssPagedMedia.margin = function(margin) {
  cssPagedMedia('@page {margin: ' + margin + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.margin('0');
/*page size*/
cssPagedMedia.size = function(size) {
  cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

var cssPagedMedia = (function() {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  return function(rule) {
    style.innerHTML = rule;
  };
}());
cssPagedMedia.size = function(size) {
  cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};
cssPagedMedia.size('portrait');
```

```css
.intLink {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.intLink {
  border: 0;
}

#toolBar1 select {
  font-size: 10px;
}

#textBox {
  width: 540px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#textBox #sourceText {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 498px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

#editMode label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="printa">

  <body onload="initDoc();">
    <form name="compForm" method="post" action="sample.php" onsubmit="if(validateMode()){this.myDoc.value=oDoc.innerHTML;return true;}return false;">
      <input type="hidden" name="myDoc">
      <div id="toolBar1">
        <select onchange="formatDoc('formatblock',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option selected>- التنسيق -</option>
          <option value="h1">عنوان 1 &lt;h1&gt;</option>
          <option value="h2">عنوان 2 &lt;h2&gt;</option>
          <option value="h3">عنوان 3 &lt;h3&gt;</option>
          <option value="h4">عنوان 4 &lt;h4&gt;</option>
          <option value="h5">عنوان 5 &lt;h5&gt;</option>
          <option value="h6">عنوان فرعي &lt;h6&gt;</option>
          <option value="p">فقرة &lt;p&gt;</option>
          <option value="pre">مهيأ مسبقا &lt;pre&gt;</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('fontname',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- الخطوط -</option>
          <option>Arial</option>
          <option>Arial Black</option>
          <option>Courier New</option>
          <option>Times New Roman</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('fontsize',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- الحجم -</option>
          <option value="1">صغير جدا</option>
          <option value="2">صغير بعض الشيء</option>
          <option value="3">عادي</option>
          <option value="4">متوسط - كبير</option>
          <option value="5">كبير</option>
          <option value="6">كبير جدا</option>
          <option value="7">أقصى</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('forecolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- اللون -</option>
          <option value="red">أحمر</option>
          <option value="blue">أزرق</option>
          <option value="green">أخضر</option>
          <option value="black">أسود</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('backcolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- الخلفية -</option>
          <option value="red">أحمر</option>
          <option value="green">أخضر</option>
          <option value="black">أسود</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="toolBar2">
        <img class="intLink" title="طباعة" onclick="printDoc();" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <img class="intLink" title="خط عريض " onclick="formatDoc('bold');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAInhI+pa+H9mJy0LhdgtrxzDG5WGFVk6aXqyk6Y9kXvKKNuLbb6zgMFADs=" />
        <img class="intLink" title="خط مائل" onclick="formatDoc('italic');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKEDAAAAAF9vj5WIbf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAAWABYAAAIjnI+py+0Po5x0gXvruEKHrF2BB1YiCWgbMFIYpsbyTNd2UwAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="تسطير" onclick="formatDoc('underline');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKECAAAAAF9vj////////yH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAWABYAAAIrlI+py+0Po5zUgAsEzvEeL4Ea15EiJJ5PSqJmuwKBEKgxVuXWtun+DwxCCgA7" />
        <img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى اليسار" onclick="formatDoc('justifyleft');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JMGELkGYxo+qzl4nKyXAAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى الوسط" onclick="formatDoc('justifycenter');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIfhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JOGI7kaZ5Bqn4sycVbAQA7" />
        <img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى اليمين" onclick="formatDoc('justifyright');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JQGDLkGYxouqzl43JyVgAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="الرجوع إلى الخلف" onclick="formatDoc('undo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKADljwliE33mOrpGjuYKl8aezxqPD+7/I19DV3NHa7P///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARR8MlJq7046807TkaYeJJBnES4EeUJvIGapWYAC0CsocQ7SDlWJkAkCA6ToMYWIARGQF3mRQVIEjkkSVLIbSfEwhdRIH4fh/DZMICe3/C4nBQBADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="التقدم إلى الأمام" onclick="formatDoc('redo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIHAB1ChDljwl9vj1iE34Kl8aPD+7/I1////yH5BAEKAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAANKeLrc/jDKSesyphi7SiEgsVXZEATDICqBVJjpqWZt9NaEDNbQK1wCQsxlYnxMAImhyDoFAElJasRRvAZVRqqQXUy7Cgx4TC6bswkAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="قائمة ذات تعداد رقمي" onclick="formatDoc('insertorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAADljwliE35GjuaezxtHa7P///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAM2eLrc/jDKSespwjoRFvggCBUBoTFBeq6QIAysQnRHaEOzyaZ07Lu9lUBnC0UGQU1K52s6n5oEADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="قائمة ذات تعداد نقطي" onclick="formatDoc('insertunorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAAB1ChF9vj1iE33mOrqezxv///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAMyeLrc/jDKSesppNhGRlBAKIZRERBbqm6YtnbfMY7lud64UwiuKnigGQliQuWOyKQykgAAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="إضافة رابط" onclick="var sLnk=prompt('Write the URL here','http:\/\/');if(sLnk&&sLnk!=''&&sLnk!='http://'){formatDoc('createlink',sLnk)}" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKAB1ChDRLY19vj3mOrpGjuaezxrCztb/I19Ha7Pv8/f///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARY8MlJq7046827/2BYIQVhHg9pEgVGIklyDEUBy/RlE4FQF4dCj2AQXAiJQDCWQCAEBwIioEMQBgSAFhDAGghGi9XgHAhMNoSZgJkJei33UESv2+/4vD4TAQA7"
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="القص" onclick="formatDoc('cut');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQSAB1ChBFNsRJTySJYwjljwkxwl19vj1dusYODhl6MnHmOrpqbmpGjuaezxrCztcDCxL/I18rL1P///////////////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAVu4CeOZGmeaKqubDs6TNnEbGNApNG0kbGMi5trwcA9GArXh+FAfBAw5UexUDAQESkRsfhJPwaH4YsEGAAJGisRGAQY7UCC9ZAXBB+74LGCRxIEHwAHdWooDgGJcwpxDisQBQRjIgkDCVlfmZqbmiEAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="النسخ" onclick="formatDoc('copy');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQcAB1ChBFNsTRLYyJYwjljwl9vj1iE31iGzF6MnHWX9HOdz5GjuYCl2YKl8ZOt4qezxqK63aK/9KPD+7DI3b/I17LM/MrL1MLY9NHa7OPs++bx/Pv8/f///////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWG4CeOZGmeaKqubOum1SQ/kPVOW749BeVSus2CgrCxHptLBbOQxCSNCCaF1GUqwQbBd0JGJAyGJJiobE+LnCaDcXAaEoxhQACgNw0FQx9kP+wmaRgYFBQNeAoGihCAJQsCkJAKOhgXEw8BLQYciooHf5o7EA+kC40qBKkAAAGrpy+wsbKzIiEAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="اللصق" onclick="formatDoc('paste');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQUAD04KTRLY2tXQF9vj414WZWIbXmOrpqbmpGjudClFaezxsa0cb/I1+3YitHa7PrkIPHvbuPs+/fvrvv8/f///////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWN4CeOZGmeaKqubGsusPvBSyFJjVDs6nJLB0khR4AkBCmfsCGBQAoCwjF5gwquVykSFbwZE+AwIBV0GhFog2EwIDchjwRiQo9E2Fx4XD5R+B0DDAEnBXBhBhN2DgwDAQFjJYVhCQYRfgoIDGiQJAWTCQMRiwwMfgicnVcAAAMOaK+bLAOrtLUyt7i5uiUhADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="المسح التام" onclick="if(validateMode()&&confirm('Are you sure?')){oDoc.innerHTML=sDefTxt};" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQbAD04KTRLYzFRjlldZl9vj1dusY14WYODhpWIbbSVFY6O7IOXw5qbms+wUbCztca0ccS4kdDQjdTLtMrL1O3YitHa7OPcsd/f4PfvrvDv8Pv5xv///////////////////yH5BAEKAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAV84CeOZGmeaKqubMteyzK547QoBcFWTm/jgsHq4rhMLoxFIehQQSAWR+Z4IAyaJ0kEgtFoLIzLwRE4oCQWrxoTOTAIhMCZ0tVgMBQKZHAYyFEWEV14eQ8IflhnEHmFDQkAiSkQCI2PDC4QBg+OAJc0ewadNCOgo6anqKkoIQA7"
        />

      </div>
      <iframe id="inlineFrameExample" name="inlineFrameExample" title="Inline Frame Example" width="0" height="0" dir="rtl" hidden="hidden">
  </iframe>
      <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true">


        <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/KDXSnOv.jpg" width="160"></div><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Lorem Ipsum</strong>
        <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
          has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
      </div>

      <p id="editMode"><input type="checkbox" name="switchMode" id="switchBox" onchange="setDocMode(this.checked);" hidden="hidden" /> </p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Send" hidden="hidden" /></p>
```

I hope this is of some help, if you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

Happy coding!

Comment: NewToJS Your answer is great but when I try to have img as logo not text it does not appear on the printed page so how can I do that with img tag

Comment: @HAMID maybe the image is too big causing it to not load in time before being added to the print. Try with a smaller image or load the image on page load and then include it upon print. I would recommend you run some tests using a small image to find out if the size/loading of the image is the issue.